# Cannot create Android project in xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, sdk, android-ndk

I have installed visual studio ultimate 2012 with Xamarin. I have set JDK, sdk and ndk path correctly. I have even set JAVA_HOME path correctly to jdk 1.7. when I tried to create new Android project, It gives me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The output is as below

```
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\Arnold\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack.exe in \. (C:\Users\Arnold\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71).
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 6.0.2
```

Comment: Try updating android SDK as explaine here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626330/object-refrence-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-i-create-new-android-ap?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Hey Arnold, can you please post your solution if you could get ride of this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried updated sdk. could not update sdk from android studio due to some technical issue. so I directly downloaded separate components from

http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/

Try this link to download everything you need for Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Try updating android SDK as explaine here [Object refrence not set to an instance of an object When I create new Android App (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626330/object-refrence-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-i-create-new-android-ap?answertab=votes#tab-top)

make sure to refer latest android SDK

Comment: Thank you, In my SDK Manager, I can see upto API 24. Should I install it or should I install API23 or API 22?

Comment: go for latest, If that helps please accept this answer