# Xamarin - Cannot create android Black app : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Week ago I upgrade my Visual Studio 2017, and now I'm unable to create an Android app in Xamarin. I have some problems and I dont know whats the main.

When I create the Blank app only the folder is create and I get this error:

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

As I read here: [Object refrence not set to an instance of an object When I create new Android App (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626330/object-refrence-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-i-create-new-android-ap)
and others posts the solution is upgrade the SDK but I can't even do that because my Tools dont contain anymore Tools/Android...

[image: Is in Spanish]

I also cannot find Xamarin SDK manager in Individuals Components as say here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin

[image: In Spanish]
And also I get these errors in Tools/Options/Xamarin:

**The package "DesignerPackage" did not load correctly.**

**The package "MonoAndroidDesignerPackage" did not load correctly.**

[image]

I reinstalled Xamarin, Restore and Repair Visual Studio and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was fixed by downloading JDK8 (I had JDK9 on my machine and had to delete it). What version JDK are you using?

Comment: I have the JDK9, I will try to download the JDK8.